# TEXstudio problem in 14.04: no info on mouse hovering

Tags: 14.04, mouse

Ubuntu 14.04: If I hover the mouse over the upper symbols in TEXstudio little yellow areas appear, but there is no text in them. 
What to do?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, so I will upvote your question.